# Why does ModelBuilder lose data sources when copy/pasting or renaming toolbox?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.2

I have a ModelBuilder with a parent model that contains several sub-models.  The parent and sub-models are contained w/in the same toolbox.  Everytime I copy&paste or rename the toolbox, the parent models shows a red x and when i open it, I can see that the submodels w/in the parent also have red x's.  The issue seem to be that the sub-models loose their input sde data sources and so I have to re-establish them and then re-add them to the parent model.  I would like to find out what causes the models to fail like this when copying or renaming.  I'm using Desktop 10.2.  The screenshot is of the parent model.  The top row shows the failed sub-models and the bottom row is me in the middle of editing and re-adding the submodels to the canvas.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @blah238, I think you will need to:

> have "Use Relative Paths" checked in all of the models' properties